# Image positioning in java swings

Tags: java, image, swing, jlabel

I have this code to add an image

```
JFrame note=new new JFrame();
JLabel label5=new JLabel();
label5.setIcon(new ImageIcon(searchresult.class.getResource("/images/expired.png")));
label5.setBounds(200,500,450,100);
note.add(label5);
```

The result I get is this [image]

I tried changing the `bounds` to other values but there is no change in the image position.The image remains at that same position.

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't set a layout to frame.

```
note.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
```

This will help you to drag your image (or whatever the component you want to add) in `center`.

Comment: it should be null... `note.setLayout(null);`, if you set it to a layout manager it will not allow you to set the bounds freely because the layout manager is the one controlling it... so by setting the layout to null  you get full control.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to position the component via `setBounds()`, you need to set the layout of the container to `null`. See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/none.html

But I would recommend to use a proper layout manager with constraints.